Unable to reach the other node using telnet
I opened port 6443 using ufw.
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
6443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
6443                       ALLOW       Anywhere
6443/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

Here are few other checks that I did ...
$ sudo nc -l 6443
nc: Address already in use

$ sudo ss -tuln | grep 6443
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                 *:6443             *:*

$ sudo iptables -L -n | grep 6443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6443
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:6443
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:6443

From the client machine -
$ ping 129.x.x.x
PING 129.x.x.x (129.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.266 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.213 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.238 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.168 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.189 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.193 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 129.x.x.x: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=0.179 ms
^C
--- 129.x.x.x ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7167ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.168/0.205/0.266/0.030 ms


$ nc -vz 129.x.x.x 22
Connection to 129.x.x.x 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!

But here is the error -
$ nc -vz 129.x.x.x 6443
nc: connect to 129.x.x.x port 6443 (tcp) failed: No route to host

What do I need to do to open this port? This port is used by kubernetes api server and without this open, I won't be able to join the node to the cluster

If the server is located on a hosted service, you will want to check that the security policy for the network allows traffic on that port.

The servers are all on chameleon cloud. They are all on a shared network.
